# Найти слова, начинающиеся на определенную букву

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите пожалуйста пример регулярного выражения.

Мне нужно найти все слова, которые начинаются на "h" (и заканчиваются, соответственно, пробелом)

То есть для строки `"I'am headline for a example"` должен быть вывод `"headline"`

Comment: [`(?:h[^\s]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/JM7mmC/1)

Comment: можно еще проще - h\w+

Comment: не забудьте про границу слова `\b`

Comment: А что делать с `l'huile`? `Chicago O'Hare International Airport`? `o-ho weak spots`?

Answer (score 1):

Одно из удачных выражений: `(?<= )h\w+`

Два выражения из комментария не обрабатываю случай `h` внутри слова:
I'am headline for a example onehehehehe
I'am headline for a example inhehehe